# After "than" grammar

Tags: grammar

Merriam Webster defines [understate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/understate) as follows:

> ....
> 1: to represent as less than is the case understate taxable income
> ....

In the phrase "to represent as less than is the case", is inversion after than used here?
Or is the subject omitted?

Comment: You have already asked a similar question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/329847/omission-of-subject-after-than). This is a dictionary definition, so it doesn't really have a subject. To underestimate something is to represent [it] as less than **is the case** - i.e. than it really is.

Comment: [Please never post pictures of text](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/600502/can-we-use-adverbs-of-frequency-with-will#comment1512593_600502). They create accessibility problems because screen readers cannot read them. They cannot be searched, saved, or quoted as text. Please edit this post to replace it with the actual text.

Comment: We don't include a "subject" in dictionary definitions of verbs (which are invariably presented in the *infinitive* form, usually with the explicit "infinitive marker" ***to***, as here). But the "**object**" of the verb could optionally be included here, as *"to represent **something** as less than is the case"* (it's completely unnecessary, though). Doing that allows us to refer back to the subject using a pronoun, with "simpler" syntax for the "than-" clause: *"to represent **something** as [being] less than **it** actually is"*.